# Access Query to Compare Two Dates

Tags: ms-access

I would like to compare one date field `[25WD]` to another `[Date closed]` via a query, with the idea of a "Yes" appearing in the results field if `[Date closed]` occurred before `[25WD]` and "No" if it didn't, but cannot seem to get it working.

The fields both exist within the same table and they are both set to hold date values.

When attempting to put the queries together, I am regularly prompted to "Enter Parameter Value" for one or both of the fields and this is where I get stuck.

I am looking for something along the lines of this:

```
If [Date closed] occurred before [25WD]
Then "Yes"
Else "No"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply is:

```
IIf([Date closed] < [25WD], "Yes", "No") As DateClosedBefore25WD
```

or:

```
Format([Date closed] < [25WD], "Yes/No") As DateClosedBefore25WD
```

In the query GUI:

```
DateClosedBefore25WD: IIf([Date closed] < [25WD], "Yes", "No")
```

or:

```
DateClosedBefore25WD: Format([Date closed] < [25WD], "Yes/No")
```

Comment: Where do I plug this code in?  I have tried entering it directly into the query design screen but it produces a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you, although I have tried both and am still prompted for a parameter value for `[25WD]` in each instance.

Comment: Then you don't have a field with that name. Correct the spelling and the query will run.